# How to detect a "love" potion?

Tags: crime

A concoction has been invented that can influence a target to fall in love with an individual. This works in two parts. The user must drink one type of potion to emit certain hormones while the unsuspecting target drinks the other version of the potion. The hormones trigger the emotions of the target, encouraging strong feelings of arousal and love in them. These substances are odorless and don't build up in the body. It evaporates from the bloodstream rather quickly, and doesn't leave traces of itself in blood, urine, or fingernails like other poisons. The affect on a target is not permanent and must be consumed at certain intervals or the affect will wear off.

This potion has the potential of being abused, and many have been taken advantaged of in society, and it has been made illegal as a result. However, there are others who have used it as an excuse to get out of responsibilities or bad decisions. There is difficulty in proving veracity of these claims because the substance is so hard to detect.

How can one detect that this potion has been used in an individual?

Comment: For comparison, how can someone "prove" that they were under the influence of alcohol a week ago when they did something ill-advised?  If there is a major social problem then someone will devise a test to detect it, as has happened with various performance enhancing drugs in sports.  But given that this is a fictitious drug it is difficult to give any meaningful answer about what the limits of such a test might be.

Comment: What is the time frame? while the compounds are still present is should be easy. The blood stream does not clear itself instantly. you also have whatever carrier is used to get the hormones into the body, Then of course you have stool samples since it is ingested.

Answer (score 6):

*Boring 'ol Detective work*.

Since the substance can't be legally traded, you must find the source. Check for dealers, interrogations.

Illegal stuff costs a lot, did his girlfriend take a large sum of cash before he broke the prenuptial arrangement and proposed in front of the office?

Did they share time together daily, so the dosis could be reapplied?

Check the trash! FBI, CIA & KGB all were fond of dumpster diving.
What a nice surprise, a small ampulle with no labels. To the forensic lab!

Ask the ISP for their logs and internet history. Get an order to check their calls. Get a cop undercover saying they have issues on their marriage. Drop hints that you would do everything to save your marriage. And record them suggesting X substance.

As humans, we think we are smarter than we really are, many a drug lord was laid low by a witness. A receipt on the garbage can. The camera of a supermarket parking lot could record your dealer selling the merchandise.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the perpetrator, not the victim.  The "certain hormones" that they are emitting should be easily detected by chemical or canine-olfactory means.  Then review the video of that person's last few hours to see who they are spending time with.  Because the hormones have a limited range, the perpetrator's behavior (in retrospect) should indicate who the intended victim is.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that /These substances are odorless and don't build up in the body. It evaporates from the bloodstream rather quickly, and doesn't leave traces /.  So unless you have a sniffer dog handy while the act is going on this won't work.